# Issue in invoking shell script in java

Tags: java, shell

I am calling a shell script in java which takes in 2 pameteres.

```
private void invokeShellScript(String script,String subject,String message)
    {
        String shellCmd = null;
        try
        {
            shellCmd = script.trim() + " " + subject + " " + message;

            Process process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(shellCmd);
            process.waitFor();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
             LOGGER.error("Exception occured while invoking the message report script");
        }
    }
```

Here when I pass the subject and message to the shell script it is not parsing the contents properly.

Here say If the subject="Hello This is a test mail".
Then the shell script consideres subject to be **Hello** and message to be **This**.

Here I am guessing the spaces in the string is causing issues.

how can I solve this issue.

Comment: The shell is probably expecting quotes around subject and message. Try to concatenate "\"" before and after subject as well as message in shellCmd.

Comment: @Johann-Christoph Jacob:Tried it and still getting the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the version of `Runtime.exec` that takes a `String[]` for the command rather than a `String`, so you can control how it is split up into words.  Or better, use `ProcessBuilder`.  You also need to either read or explicitly discard the process's output streams before calling `waitFor` or things may block

```
try {
  ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(script, subject, message);
  pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
  pb.redirectOutput(new File("/dev/null"));
  Process process = pb.start();
  process.waitFor();
}
catch(Exception e) {
  LOGGER.error("Exception occured while invoking the message report script");
}
```

(`Process.redirectOutput` is a Java 7 invention, if you're still using 6 you'll have to read and discard the contents of `process.getOutputStream()` yourself before invoking `waitFor`).

Answer (score 2):

Try quoting the strings when you pass them to shell.

So either

```
"\"Hello This is a test mail\""
```

or

```
"'Hello This is a test mail'"
```

(in java)

Comment: Tried both same problem.I either get \Hello or 'Hello as the subject and get This as the message.

Answer (score 0):

Try puttin all your argument separately argument using arraylist and provide that list as commands to `ProcessBuilder` .

```
final List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();                

commands.add(Script.trim());
commands.add(subject);
commands.add(message);

ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
```

This should work perfectly fine as java will treat them as separate arguements.

Comment: @DarkMatter, can you please try this